# Database design: should I use a mapping table?

Tags: database, database-design

Using a question and answer site like this as an example.  Say I have `question`, `answer`, and `comment` tables.  Questions and answers can each have multiple comments.

Would it be best to:

1. create `QuestionComment`, and `AnswerComment`tables to map from questions/answers to comments (each containing the question/answer pk and comment pk)?
2. Or should I only have the comment table containing 2 nullable foreign keys to question and answer (one of which will always be null since a comment can apply only to a single "item")?

It seems like (1) maintains referential integrity while (2) is more compact.  Is one preferred over the other?  Should mapping tables be reserved only for many-to-many relationships?

Comment: Are you using a domain model, or will you be accessing the database structure directly in memory (e.g. using ADO.NET DataTables)?

Answer (score 1):

Will you use both comments in the same way?  If so, then (2) otherwise (1)

If you use (1), you can create a view over both tables to make them appear as one.

In case (2), you can add a Trigger to enforce there being only one Foreign Key column being populated per row, or as @Ronnis suggested using a CHECK constraint (a better technique).

Comment: Thanks. (2) just "feels" weird to have 2 nullable foreign keys and "hope" that the application takes care of integrity plus the logic to check which is populated..

Comment: I guess what I mean is that there is nothing preventing both foreign keys from getting populated which doesn't make sense since a comment can't apply to both a question and an answer (maybe it can but its easy to suppose a scenario where this wouldn't make sense).  Is there a way to enforce this xor condition within the dbms?

Comment: @jmk23: if your dbms supports the CHECK clause, you can implement the "xor" condition you mention. CHECK((fk1 is null and fk2 is not null) or (fk2 is null and fk1 is not null))

Answer (score 0):

I've seen either approach done in practice, but I prefer (1) a little more:

I think (1) expresses your domain a little more clearly to someone browsing the schema - they'll see Answer and AnswerComment right next to each other.  If answer comments and question comments are in the same table you have to drill down into the comment table to see to which object a comment can belong.

If you're using a [domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model) with separation between domain objects and persistence, the question is moot: it doesn't matter whether you store them in the same table or different tables.  (And they would be separate classes only if they behave differently.)